# Inferring type from argument's return type

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14

I understand that a template cannot infer a type from assignment, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
T aFunction (int a) { /*...*/ }; // This obviously won't work
```

And it's pretty evident why. But this *will* work:

```
template <typename T>
T aFunction (T a, T b) { return a + b; }; // a-ok
```

'cause `T` will be inferred from the arguments. I want to kinda extrapolate from that:

```
template <typename T>
T aFunction (std::function<T(int)> a) { return a(3);};
                           ^
                           |
  I specified it! ----------
```

so that when used, there's no ambiguity on what the function should do:

```
std::function<double(int)> blah = [](int x){ return x / 2.0f; };
aFunction(blah);
```

Alas, the compiler won't cooperate with me:

> No matching member function for call to 'aFunction'
>
> Candidate template ignored: could not match
>   'function' against '(lambda at
>   file.hpp:274:16)'

Is there a way to make this happen?, short of template specialization (this is a **very** generic class), or a dummy argument (I'm not that desperate yet).

---

**P.D.:**

Full disclosure: Above was just a simplification of the problem, exactly what I need is:

```
template <typename T>
class MyStuff {

    template <typename ReturnType>
    MyStuff<ReturnType> aFunction(std::function<ReturnType(T)> a){ 
        /*for each stuff in MyStuff do a(stuff)*/ 
    }
}
```

Where `MyStuff` contains properties of type `T` and a bunch of `inline` functions, such as `aFunction`.

Comment: what happened to the `template` keyword ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki sorry, I ate it. Editing now. -- Done

Comment: What do you mean "the compiler won't cooperate with me."? Any error message?

Comment: @songyuanyao adding error messages. -- Done

Comment: Sadly, I cannot reproduce (It actually works) : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4ebbfb5e9f594fa

Comment: My guess would be that you make a direct call using a lambda without embedding it into an `std::function` somewhere (not displayed in your question): you can't have both template parameter deduction and implicit conversions at the same time

Comment: @javaLover well, I'll be damned. You are right. When removing all the context, that function by itself works. And I wasted the whole day chasing ghosts... I'm so sorry everyone! Thanks for your time! I'll delete this question in a bit.

Comment: @whitelionV  IMHO, you don't have to delete it.  It is interesting question.  Your question makes me test, and I just know that template deduction can be use extensively because of it.  The only thing you miss is to provide full mcve, which is not really bad because you already provide a good tiny snippet.

Comment: @javaLover That's another option, I could update with the context in case anyone happen to stumble upon the same problem. Thanks to you all I found out the problem was a set of functions declared auto that returned a lamdba, and since this class has every possible test case written, it exploded everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this works:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct MyStuff {
    template <typename ReturnType>
    MyStuff<ReturnType> aFunction(std::function<ReturnType(T)> a){ 
        return {};
    }
};

int main() {
    MyStuff<int> stuff;
    std::function<double(int)> fn = [](int) { return 0.; };
    stuff.aFunction(fn);
}
```

Instead this doesn't work:

```
int main() {
    MyStuff<int> stuff;
    stuff.aFunction([](int) { return 0.; });
}
```

And the error is the one posted in the question:

> note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function' against '(lambda at main.cpp:15:21)'

The reason is that type deduction works only for exact type. No conversions are allowed. In your case the compiler should deduce first of all the return type of the lambda, than convert it to an `std::function` somehow and finally deduce the return type of the function from the one constructed by using the lambda.
This is not how type deduction works.

You can work around it with something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyStuff {
    template <typename F>
    auto aFunction(F &&f) -> MyStuff<decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::declval<T>()))> { 
        return {};
    }
};
```

See it on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51d7fac85a6b0c2f).